# Access JSON fields with numeric keys

Tags: c#, json

I want to access some address of pictures in a JSON, but the field name is a number and in c# a number is not a valid name for a variable...

My JSON:

```
{
  "id":3441,
  "name":"test",
  "address": {
    "1":"url.com\/45.jpg",
    "2":"url.com\/23.jpg",
    "3":"url.com\/65.jpg",
    "4":"url.com\/789.jpg",
  },
  "count":2
}
```

My code in C#: (`HrmlResult` is my JSON)

```
dynamic stuff1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HtmlResult);
string address= stuff1.address;        //It Works
string allPics = stuff1.pic;           //It Works

firstPicTextBox.Text= stuff1.pic.1;    //compiler Error
secondPicTextBox.Text = stuff1.pic[2]; //runtime Error
```

What should I do?!
Thank you all...

Comment: where is 'pic' in json?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create Model object with properties, as in found json you're expecting.

Then, for number properties, you can use `JsonProperty` attribute to name the property as number, for example:

```
class MyModel {
   [JsonProperty("2")]
   public string Two {get; set;}
}
```

and then use `DeserializeObject<MyModel>` version

This is simplified example, for your object you have to maintain the hierarchy and probably have another class for 'address' property and use it as property type in the main model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to modify the JSON, that's your best bet. What you have seems like it should be in an array:

```
{
    "id":3441,
    "name":"test",
    "address":[
        "url.com\/45.jpg",
        "url.com\/23.jpg",
        "url.com\/65.jpg",
        "url.com\/789.jpg"
    ],
    "count":2
}
```

From there, your address is a simple array of strings, rather than a numbered key-value pair collection.