# Handle JSON Numeric Variable

Tags: c#, .net, json

Hello I have JSON like this :

```
ratings_total: {
   1: "1",
   2: 0,
   3: 0,
   4: 0,
   5: "3"
}
```

How can we declare the numeric variable in the C# class?

Comment: If you're using JSON.net the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19213291

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access JSON fields with numeric keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213186/access-json-fields-with-numeric-keys)

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ratings_total")]
    public Dictionary<int,int> RatingsTotal { get; set; }
}
```

```
var json = @"{
    ""ratings_total"": {
        ""1"": ""1"",
        ""2"": 0,
        ""3"": 0,
        ""4"": 0,
        ""5"": ""3""
    }
}";

// Convert string to a stream (only nessesary for this example)
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(json);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;

// Settings to enable dictionary serialization
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Foo), settings);

// Deserialize object
var obj = (Foo)ser.ReadObject(stream);
```