# JSON with 'nameless' sub-fields to C#

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the follow JSON (I do not control the source) using JSON.NET into a C# class or classes unsuccessfully.  How do I deal with the 'error' field.  It seems to consist of an integer and a string but those subfields are not named.

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "data": "this is a string",
  "error": {
    "123": "Something went wrong, fix it"
  }
}
```

This similar to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837977/json-to-c-sharp-list-fields-without-sub-field-names-in-json), though in this case 'data' and 'error' do not contain a collection.

This, for example, does not work...

```
public class ApiError
{
    int Number;
    string Message;
};

public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public string Status;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public string Data;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
    public ApiError Error;
};

var y = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(SampleJson);
// y.Error.Number and y.Error.Message are both 0/null.
```

Comment: It's a key value pair - "123" is the key, "Something went wrong, fix it" is the value.  The `{ }` denote it's an object (and a child of "error").  In other words, "error" is the key and the `{ }` is the value for "error".

Comment: I see that, but the "123" how do I define my C# class to parse a field that is not prefixed by a field name?

Comment: I was going to recommend a converter like [json2chsarp](http://json2csharp.com/), but interestingly enough it yields a class for "Error" with one member - "__invalid_name_123".   I don't do a lot with JSON - but the problem arises because "123" is not a valid name for a property in C#.

Comment: I sort of feel as though it is improperly formatted JSON, but I have to assume there is a way around it.

Comment: @Tony Er... Your own question already shows a valid way of dealing with properties where the JSON key name does not match the C# property name. It's not necessarily the *best* approach, but you should have been able to come up with at least that on your own. You can have a C# property `Error123` mapped to a JSON property `123`.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19213291/745969) - just use "123" for the property name for this JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a field/property in C# that starts with digits. So in your example the object for "error" can simply be a Dictionary. All JSON is just key / value pairs in the end.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error")]
public Dictionary<int, string> Errors;
```

Comment: I had assumed JSON.NET would have expected a collection if I were to use Dictionary<>.  Guess not.  I knew there was an easy answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, a JSON object **is** a collection of key/value pairs after all. That's the beauty of JSON: when you get right down to it, JSON is a vehicle for <string, string> KVPs.